# how to resolve "Layout has more than 80 views, bad for performance"?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, tablerow

I'm doing a layout a bit complex, just that I can't fix the error that is indicated by LINT **(...has blackberries than 80 views, bad for performance)**
This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Activity_schedapunti">


    <TableLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".7"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/esame_visivo"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>

            <TextView 
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/punteggio_parziale"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".7"
                android:orientation="horizontal">               
                 <TextView 
                     android:id="@+id/textview_aspetto"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="@string/aspetto"/>                  
               <TextView 
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="@string/coeff_x1"
                     android:textStyle="bold"
                     android:textColor="@color/light_yellow"/>
               <EditText 
                     android:id="@+id/edittext_aspetto"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                     android:inputType="number"
                     android:singleLine="true" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview_puteggio_parziale_aspetto"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".3"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".7"
                android:orientation="horizontal">               
                 <TextView 
                     android:id="@+id/textview_punti_colore"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="@string/colore"/>                   
               <TextView 
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="@string/coeff_x2"
                     android:textStyle="bold"
                     android:textColor="@color/light_yellow"/>
               <EditText 
                     android:id="@+id/edittext_punti_colore"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                     android:inputType="number"
                     android:singleLine="true" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview_puteggio_parziale_colore"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".3"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".7"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/esame_olfattivo"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/punteggio_parziale"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".7"
                android:orientation="horizontal">               
                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/textview_punti_intensita"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/intensita"/>                 
                <TextView 
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="@string/coeff_x1"
                   android:textStyle="bold"
                   android:textColor="@color/light_yellow"/>
                <EditText 
                   android:id="@+id/edittext_punti_intensita"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                   android:inputType="number"
                   android:singleLine="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview_puteggio_parziale_intensita"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".3"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".7"
                android:orientation="horizontal">               
                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/textview_punti_complessita"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/complessita"/>                   
                <TextView 
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="@string/coeff_x2"
                   android:textStyle="bold"
                   android:textColor="@color/light_yellow"/>
                <EditText 
                   android:id="@+id/edittext_punti_complessita"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                   android:inputType="number"
                   android:singleLine="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview_puteggio_parziale_complessita"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".3"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".7"
                android:orientation="horizontal">               
                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/textview_punti_qualita"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/qualita"/>                   
                <TextView 
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="@string/coeff_x3"
                   android:textStyle="bold"
                   android:textColor="@color/light_yellow"/>
                <EditText 
                   android:id="@+id/edittext_punti_qualita"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                   android:inputType="number"
                   android:singleLine="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview_puteggio_parziale_qualita"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".3"/>
        </TableRow>




        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".7"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/esame_gusto_olfattivo"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/punteggio_parziale"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".7"
                android:orientation="horizontal">               
                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/textview_punti_struttura"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/struttura"/>                 
                <TextView 
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="@string/coeff_x1"
                   android:textStyle="bold"
                   android:textColor="@color/light_yellow"/>
                <EditText 
                   android:id="@+id/edittext_punti_struttura"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                   android:inputType="number"
                   android:singleLine="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview_puteggio_parziale_struttura"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".3"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".7"
                android:orientation="horizontal">               
                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/textview_punti_equilibrio"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/equilibrio"/>                
                <TextView 
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="@string/coeff_x1"
                   android:textStyle="bold"
                   android:textColor="@color/light_yellow"/>
                <EditText 
                   android:id="@+id/edittext_punti_equilibrio"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                   android:inputType="number"
                   android:singleLine="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview_puteggio_parziale_equilibrio"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".3"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".7"
                android:orientation="horizontal">               
                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/textview_punti_intensita_gusto_olfattivo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/intensita"/>                 
                <TextView 
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="@string/coeff_x1"
                   android:textStyle="bold"
                   android:textColor="@color/light_yellow"/>
                <EditText 
                   android:id="@+id/edittext_punti_intensita_gusto_olfattivo"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                   android:inputType="number"
                   android:singleLine="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview_puteggio_parziale_intensita_gusto_olfattivo"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".3"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".7"
                android:orientation="horizontal">               
                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/textview_punti_persistenza"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/persistenza"/>                   
                <TextView 
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="@string/coeff_x2"
                   android:textStyle="bold"
                   android:textColor="@color/light_yellow"/>
                <EditText 
                   android:id="@+id/edittext_punti_persistenza"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                   android:inputType="number"
                   android:singleLine="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview_puteggio_parziale_persistenza"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".3"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".7"
                android:orientation="horizontal">               
                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/textview_punti_qualita_gusto_olfattivo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/qualita"/>                   
                <TextView 
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="@string/coeff_x3"
                   android:textStyle="bold"
                   android:textColor="@color/light_yellow"/>
                <EditText 
                   android:id="@+id/edittext_punti_qualita_gusto_olfattivo"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                   android:inputType="number"
                   android:singleLine="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview_puteggio_parziale_qualita_gusto_olfattivo"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".3"/>
        </TableRow>


        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".7"
                android:orientation="horizontal">               
                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/textview_punti_armonia"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/armonia"/>                   
                <TextView 
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="@string/coeff_x3"
                   android:textStyle="bold"
                   android:textColor="@color/light_yellow"/>
                <EditText 
                   android:id="@+id/edittext_punti_armonia"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                   android:inputType="number"
                   android:singleLine="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textview_puteggio_parziale_armonia"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight=".3"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".7"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/punteggio_totale"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="@color/light_yellow"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@android:color/black"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I read to use a ListView, but how should I to do? Not all the rows are equal, or in any case there are some elements in the middle which are not equal to all other rows!

**Image:**

[image]

Comment: Can you post an image of how it should look? This would probably help. With a `ListView` you can use a custom `layout` in your `Adapter` and decide to show/not show certain `View`s depending on some value, if this works for you.

Comment: what layout are you trying to implement? A screenshot would be nice. Also using this many views would slow your app

Comment: @codeMagic

I add the image ;)

Comment: Please see my answer, you need to extend base adapter and do some conditional logic based on what section you are in to determine how many rows to add

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This definitely looks like a good candidate for a `ListView`. As I stated in my comment, you can use a custom `layout` in your `Adapter`. I don't know how you are getting your data for it so I can't say exactly how to check but in each round of `getView()` you can check the data and decide which `View`s to show/hide.

Simply create the `layout` with the `TextView`s, etc... that each row might need, looks like probably inside of a vertical `LinearLayout` with horizontal `LinearLayout`s inside or just a `RelativeLayout` then change `visibility` to `visible`/`gone` depending on what you need.

If you are unfamiliar with doing this then you can see [this tutorial](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html&sa=U&ei=DdyUUpa4M8OCyQH00oGwAg&ved=0CAYQFjAA&client=internal-uds-cse&usg=AFQjCNHLr6rJUBFHQki0yQVHOMXm9IePhw) on doing it.

[Adapter Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html)

[ListView Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

As pointed out in a comment, you could inflate different `layout`s in your `getView()` method of your `Adapter` if you have very different `layouts` which may make toggling `visibility` a bad approach. This just depends on your data and `layout`s.

Comment: Or `ListView` also support multiple row types, instead of show hide you can add suppport for multiple row types and inflate appropriate row from `getView()`.

Comment: I solved!! Thanks!!
I don't know if i solved correctly....but...I solved with implementing a ListView

Comment: Haha...you're welcome! If you solved with `ListView` and it is working then you probably solved correctly.

Comment: Its bad practice for the visbile/gone thing. I think its better to do what @M-WaJeEh said

Comment: @MobileMon I'm not sure how bad it is. That just depends on how it is implemented and what the data will be like. I have a `ListView` using that because I have one row that shows certain `ImageButton`s depending on what comes from the server. But, yes, that suggestion should work, also. The point is that a custom `View` needs to be used either way

Answer (score 1):

you must use a MergeAdapter where you can merge differents adapter to only one. For example titles and values. I got the code from StackOverflow but i can't find the topic so i paste here the code that i found.

```
package com.mydocum.adapters;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SectionIndexer;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
* Adapter that merges multiple child adapters and views into a single
* contiguous whole.
* 
* Adapters used as pieces within MergeAdapter must have view type IDs
* monotonically increasing from 0. Ideally, adapters also have distinct ranges
* for their row ids, as returned by getItemId().
* 
*/
public class MergeAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SectionIndexer {
    protected ArrayList<ListAdapter> pieces = new ArrayList<ListAdapter>();
    protected String noItemsText;

    /**
    * Stock constructor, simply chaining to the superclass.
    */
    public MergeAdapter() {
        super();
    }

    /**
    * Adds a new adapter to the roster of things to appear in the aggregate
    * list.
    * 
    * @param adapter
    *            Source for row views for this section
    */
    public void addAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
        pieces.add(adapter);
        adapter.registerDataSetObserver(new CascadeDataSetObserver());
    }

    /**
    * Get the data item associated with the specified position in the data set.
    * 
    * @param position
    *            Position of the item whose data we want
    */
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        for (ListAdapter piece : pieces) {
            int size = piece.getCount();

            if (position < size) {
                return (piece.getItem(position));
            }

            position -= size;
        }

        return (null);
    }

    public void setNoItemsText(String text){
        noItemsText = text;
    }

    /**
    * Get the adapter associated with the specified position in the data set.
    * 
    * @param position
    *            Position of the item whose adapter we want
    */
    public ListAdapter getAdapter(int position) {
        for (ListAdapter piece : pieces) {
            int size = piece.getCount();

            if (position < size) {
                return (piece);
            }

            position -= size;
        }

        return (null);
    }

    /**
    * How many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter.
    */
    public int getCount() { 
        int total = 0;

        for (ListAdapter piece : pieces) {
            total += piece.getCount();
        }

        if(total == 0 && noItemsText != null){
            total = 1;
        }

        return (total);
    }

    /**
    * Returns the number of types of Views that will be created by getView().
    */
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        int total = 0;

        for (ListAdapter piece : pieces) {
            total += piece.getViewTypeCount();
        }

        return (Math.max(total, 1)); // needed for setListAdapter() before
                                        // content add'
    }

    /**
    * Get the type of View that will be created by getView() for the specified
    * item.
    * 
    * @param position
    *            Position of the item whose data we want
    */
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        int typeOffset = 0;
        int result = -1;

        for (ListAdapter piece : pieces) {
            int size = piece.getCount();

            if (position < size) {
                result = typeOffset + piece.getItemViewType(position);
                break;
            }

            position -= size;
            typeOffset += piece.getViewTypeCount();
        }

        return (result);
    }

    /**
    * Are all items in this ListAdapter enabled? If yes it means all items are
    * selectable and clickable.
    */
    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return (false);
    }

    /**
    * Returns true if the item at the specified position is not a separator.
    * 
    * @param position
    *            Position of the item whose data we want
    */
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        for (ListAdapter piece : pieces) {
            int size = piece.getCount();

            if (position < size) {
                return (piece.isEnabled(position));
            }

            position -= size;
        }

        return (false);
    }

    /**
    * Get a View that displays the data at the specified position in the data
    * set.
    * 
    * @param position
    *            Position of the item whose data we want
    * @param convertView
    *            View to recycle, if not null
    * @param parent
    *            ViewGroup containing the returned View
    */
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        for (ListAdapter piece : pieces) {
            int size = piece.getCount();

            if (position < size) {

                return (piece.getView(position, convertView, parent));
            }

            position -= size;
        }

        if(noItemsText != null){
            TextView text = new TextView(parent.getContext());
            text.setText(noItemsText);
            return text;
        }

        return (null);
    }

    /**
    * Get the row id associated with the specified position in the list.
    * 
    * @param position
    *            Position of the item whose data we want
    */
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        for (ListAdapter piece : pieces) {
            int size = piece.getCount();

            if (position < size) {
                return (piece.getItemId(position));
            }

            position -= size;
        }

        return (-1);
    }

    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
        int position = 0;

        for (ListAdapter piece : pieces) {
            if (piece instanceof SectionIndexer) {
                Object[] sections = ((SectionIndexer) piece).getSections();
                int numSections = 0;

                if (sections != null) {
                    numSections = sections.length;
                }

                if (section < numSections) {
                    return (position + ((SectionIndexer) piece)
                            .getPositionForSection(section));
                } else if (sections != null) {
                    section -= numSections;
                }
            }

            position += piece.getCount();
        }

        return (0);
    }

    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        int section = 0;

        for (ListAdapter piece : pieces) {
            int size = piece.getCount();

            if (position < size) {
                if (piece instanceof SectionIndexer) {
                    return (section + ((SectionIndexer) piece)
                            .getSectionForPosition(position));
                }

                return (0);
            } else {
                if (piece instanceof SectionIndexer) {
                    Object[] sections = ((SectionIndexer) piece).getSections();

                    if (sections != null) {
                        section += sections.length;
                    }
                }
            }

            position -= size;
        }

        return (0);
    }

    public Object[] getSections() {
        ArrayList<Object> sections = new ArrayList<Object>();

        for (ListAdapter piece : pieces) {
            if (piece instanceof SectionIndexer) {
                Object[] curSections = ((SectionIndexer) piece).getSections();

                if (curSections != null) {
                    for (Object section : curSections) {
                        sections.add(section);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (sections.size() == 0) {
            return (null);
        }

        return (sections.toArray(new Object[0]));
    }

    private class CascadeDataSetObserver extends DataSetObserver {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidated() {
            notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    }
}
```

Here how you need to use it:

```
    MergeAdapter adapter = new MergeAdapter();
AdapterA adapterA = new AdapterA(...);
AdapterB adapterB = new AdapterB(...);

adapter.addAdapter(adapterA);
adapter.addAdapter(adapterB);

listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In the listview you will have the adapterA and andapterB one after other and shower correcly. The two adapter can have diffente object.

Bye.

Answer (score 0):

Wow this is bad, use a ListView instead of a TableView and dynamically add rows based on what section you are in.

I would extend BaseAdapter to achieve this