# Reducing layout views in an Activity for better performance

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, textview

I have an activity with a scrollable view. I also have containers that all have the same structure - consist of imageButton and also several textViews that serve as a description. The whole thing looks like that:

[image]

The problem is that there are around 30 elements with the same structure and when each one of them has so many textViews I get the warning -

> Layout has more than 80 views, bad for performance.

The reason why I have so many views is because of the different formatting of the different words. How would it be possible to reduce the views and still get the same formatting?

P.S. I already read that [how to resolve "Layout has more than 80 views, bad for performance"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223628/how-to-resolve-layout-has-more-than-80-views-bad-for-performance) . But this doesn't help me, since all the information that I have, should be static and always visible.

Comment: Why are you using a scrollview and not a listview?

Comment: @tyczj What difference would that make when I still have the textviews?

Comment: TextViews can contain images as compound drawables. No need for extra ImageViews.

Comment: use recyclerView instead of using different separate views.

Comment: It is helpful if you can show how you are getting the **DATA** in _**API**_. so we could look for better responsive layout or view

Comment: @ladyeli555 beause you wont have more than 80 views. a row in a recyclerview will only contain the minimum amount of views needed for each row (lets just say 10 views in this case). A row in your example would contain an imageview and some text views. A new row is created for each item in the list and far more efficient than having it all in a scollview

Comment: Thank you very much for all your comments!

Answer (score 2):

You will want to set up your layout using a RecyclerView.

> If your app needs to display a scrolling list of elements based on large data sets (or data that frequently changes), you should use RecyclerView.

[Android Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#java) has some pretty good documentation on how to set this up. Also, here is a video tutorial on RecyclerView by [SlideNerd](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wq2o4EbM74k). He has a pretty good series for android developers.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what J. Jefferson said about RecyclerView. As you mentioned in your initial post:

> The reason why I have so many views is because of the **different
>   formatting of the different words**. How would it be possible to reduce
>   the views and still get the same formatting?

You can do different text formatting without creating a separate textview. Have a look at the following https://stackoverflow.com/a/41953808/8312634